# Extract JSON File from S3 to Redshift

Tags: sql, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I wanted to extract an JSON files data from S3 bucket to redshift through SQL but there is JSON file has recorded the data in some other format which I am not aware how to extract.

{"data": [{"description": "hi.!!", "assignedFolder": "160a6dc4-83d", "extensions": {"effort": {"expandedEffortEstimated": [], "highLevelEffortEstimated": {"unit": "Points"}, "effortSpent": [], "expandedEffortRemaining": [{"id": "2022-01-20", "effortLoggedDate": "2022-01-19T18:30:00.000Z", "unit": "Points", "effort": 0}], "effortEstimatedLocal": {"unit": "Points", "effort": 0}, "effortEstimatedRecursiveSum": {"unit": "Points", "effort": 0}, "effortRemainingLocalSum": {"unit": "Points", "effort": 0}, "effortRemainingRecursiveSum": {"unit": "Points", "effort": 0}, "effortSpentLocalSum": {"unit": "Points", "effort": 0}, "effortSpentRecursiveSum": {"unit": "Points", "effort": 0}}, "backlog": {"priority": 0.95}, "tt": {"status": "Open"}}, "title": "Insight", "customFields": {"string": [{"id": "market_place", "value": "US"}, {"id": "team", "value": "ASIN Review Team"}, {"id": "product_type", "value": "seat"}, {"id": "kindly_add_case_id_or_tt", "value": "Random123"}, {"id": "link_for_case_id_or_tt", "value": "https://abc"}

The column keep on repeating in this manner. Can we extract these kind of data directly with the help of SQL?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the `data` element contains a *list*. This is **not** the correct format for loading into Redshift as JSON.

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "description": "hi.!!",
            "assignedFolder": "160a6dc4-83d",
            "extensions": {
                "effort": {
                    "expandedEffortEstimated": [],
                    "highLevelEffortEstimated": {
                        "unit": "Points"
                    },
                    "effortSpent": [],
                    "expandedEffortRemaining": [
                        {
                            "id": "2022-01-20",
                            "effortLoggedDate": "2022-01-19T18:30:00.000Z",
                            "unit": "Points",
                            "effort": 0
                        }
                    ],
                    "effortEstimatedLocal": {
                        "unit": "Points",
                        "effort": 0
                    }
                    ...
                },
                "backlog": {
                    "priority": 0.95
                },
                "tt": {
                    "status": "Open"
                }
            },
            "title": "Insight",
            "customFields": {
                "string": [
                    {
                        "id": "market_place",
                        "value": "US"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "team",
                        "value": "ASIN Review Team"
                    },
                    ...
```

You would need to pre-process this file to convert it into an appropriate format (eg removing the 'data' level and converting to [JSON Lines](https://jsonlines.org/) format.

See also: [COPY from JSON format - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-json.html)